# How do I get this scope on top of my other lines?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphdrawing

Yo

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (0,3cm); 
\draw (0.5cm,0) -- (0.5cm,3cm);
\draw (3cm,0) -- (3cm,3cm);
\draw (3.5cm,0) -- (3.5cm,3cm);
\draw (0,0) arc (0:180:-1.75cm);
\draw (0.5cm,0) arc (0:180:-1.25cm);


\draw [fill=blue,blue] (0,0) rectangle (0.5cm,1cm);
\draw [fill=blue,blue] (3cm,0) rectangle (3.5cm,2.5cm);
\draw[dashed] (0.5cm,1cm) -- (4.5cm,1cm);
\draw[dashed] (3.5cm,2.5cm) -- (4.5cm,2.5cm);
\draw[<->] (4.5cm,1cm) -- (4.5cm,2.5cm) node[midway,right] {$\Delta h$};

\def\Radius{1.75cm}
\def\radius{1.25cm}
 \begin{scope}[even odd rule]
 \clip circle[radius=\Radius];
  \clip[rotate=0] (0,0) -- (0:\Radius) arc (0:-180:\Radius)--cycle;
 \fill[blue] 
  circle[radius=\Radius]
  circle[radius=\radius]
    ;
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

For some reason, the scope isn't on top of my other lines although I have set them all up to start at (0,0).
Any suggestions on how I make this work?
[image: Tikz-Drawing]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please always provide a full MWE that also comprises your `documentclass` etc.

Answer (score 6):

This is not an answer but just a comment. You can do that much easier. (**EDIT**: fixed the water level on the left, sorry, did not pay enough attention.)

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [double distance=0.5cm] (0.25,3) -- (0.25,0) arc(0:180:-1.5cm)
-- (3.25,3);
\draw [blue,line width=0.5cm] (0.25,1) -- (0.25,0) arc(0:180:-1.5cm)
-- (3.25,2.5);
\draw[dashed] (0.5cm,1cm) -- (4.5cm,1cm);
\draw[dashed] (3.5cm,2.5cm) -- (4.5cm,2.5cm);
\draw[<->] (4.5cm,1cm) -- (4.5cm,2.5cm) node[midway,right] {$\Delta h$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Neat and simple solution.

Comment: @Diaa Thanks for pinging me, this made me spot a(nother) bug, and thanks for your nice comment! ;-)

Answer (score 5):

This is because you draw the first shape using `arc` and the second by drawing a circle. A circle is drawn around its center which you defined implicitly as `(0,0)`, and hence the shift. You can shift the scope by 1.75cm to fit it to the other shapes.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\fill[blue] (0,0) rectangle (0.5cm,1cm); 
\fill[blue] (3cm,0) rectangle (3.5cm,2.5cm); 

\def\Radius{1.75cm} 
\def\radius{1.25cm} 
\begin{scope}[xshift=1.75cm,even odd rule] 
  \clip (0,0) -- (0:\Radius) arc (0:-180:\Radius) -- cycle; 
  \fill[blue] circle[radius=\Radius] circle[radius=\radius]; 
\end{scope} 

\draw (0,0) -- (0,3cm); 
\draw (0.5cm,0) -- (0.5cm,3cm); 
\draw (3cm,0) -- (3cm,3cm); 
\draw (3.5cm,0) -- (3.5cm,3cm); 
\draw (0,0) arc (0:180:-1.75cm); 
\draw (0.5cm,0) arc (0:180:-1.25cm);

\draw[dashed] (0.5cm,1cm) -- (4.5cm,1cm); 
\draw[dashed] (3.5cm,2.5cm) -- (4.5cm,2.5cm); 
\draw[<->] (4.5cm,1cm) -- (4.5cm,2.5cm) node[midway,right] {$\Delta h$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Edit: I rearranged the shapes so that the blue shape is behind the lines. This way, the lines will be visible.

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: I am sorry for asking this simple question, but could you refer me the section in the TikZ manual where I can understand what the scope environment does here in your code?

Comment: I just used this approach because the the OP also used it. The scope is mainly used to make clipping possible (2.11 „Clipping a Path“ on page 35 of the current manual). If you only want to clip a certain part of your drawing you have to use such a scope. Everything in this scope will then be clipped, but the rest of the picture will not be affected by the clipping (see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330882/understanding-clip-and-scope).

Comment: I highly appreciate your consideration to respond to my inquiry. I will certainly look at what you referred to. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

slightly modified code of the interesting [marmot's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot) "comment" (+1). it exploit more possibilities of `double` path option . for exercise :-)

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[DS/.style={double distance=5mm, semithick, double=#1}]
\draw [DS=white]    (0,3) -- (0,0)
                    (3,2.5) -- (3,3);
\draw [DS=blue!50]  (0,0) arc(0:180:-1.5cm) -- (3,2.5);
%
\draw[densely dashed]   (0.25,0.0) -- (4.45,0.0)
                        (3.25,2.5) -- (4.45,2.5);
\draw[<->] (4.35,0) -- node[right] {$\Delta h$} (4.35,2.5) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]